# How can I configure webpack to handle image paths in SCSS files

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, urlloader, vue-loader

I have a project using the Vue CLI with the webpack-simple template. I'm pulling in an NPM package that I'm working on that provides sass files. Some of the sass files have url's to images within the NPM propject. 
Here is an example of the style in the NPM package.

```
background: url("../../../assets/icons/icon-close-blue.svg") no-repeat center;
```

The image `icon-close-blue.svg` is located in the NPM package relative to the SCSS file.

I'm pulling the scss file to my project like this

```
@import "~@chewy/design-system/src/design-system.scss";
```

When I start up the dev server with yarn I get this error.

```
./node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js?
{"omit":1,"remove":true}!./node_modules/vue-style-
loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-
compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-
7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-
loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?
type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: 
Can't resolve '../../../assets/icons/checkmark-green.svg' in 
'/Users/dsteinberg/Code/chewy-design-platform/src'
```

Here is my webpack config

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    src: './src/main.js',
    pages: './src/pages.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/',
    filename: '[name].build.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            scss: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
              fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
            }),
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            attrs: [':data-src']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '/static/img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '/static/media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '/static/fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].style.css")
  ]
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the NPM folder structure and the scss file with the url.]

Is there anything I can do to get webpack to handle these image paths?

Comment: does checkmark-green.svg actually exist at that path?

Comment: I does exist in the NPM package at that path

Comment: How can it exists inside the npm package at that path if its going back 3 directories from the src, but is only located 1 directory deep

Comment: It's actually 4 directories. I updated it and that still didn't fix it. I'm adding a screenshot so you can see what the project looks like.